# Automating Mounting of DavFS share

Tags: command-line, bash, mount, fstab, davfs2

So I have the problem that I have a WebDAV share that requires me to be logged into a VPN in order for it to be available. And in general, I have a lot of shares that I have access to but that aren't always available. So I have an assortment of shell scripts to create mount points and then mount the cifs share for me. I.e.

```
#!/bin/bash

# CLI ARGS
LONG_ARGS=unmount::
SHORT_ARGS=u::
OPTS=$(getopt -a -n weather --options $SHORT_ARGS --longoptions $LONG_ARGS -- "$@")
eval set -- "$OPTS"

mount=true
while : 
do
        case "$1" in
                -u | --unmount )
                mount=false
                echo "Unmounting and removing Folder"
                shift 2;
                ;;

                -- )
                shift;
                break
                ;;

                * )
                echo "Unexpected option $1"
                exit 2
                ;;
        esac
done


if $mount
then
        sudo mkdir /mnt/some-mount
        sudo mount -t cifs -o username=uname,password=password //1.1.1.1/remote-mount /mnt/some-mount -o rw,uid=1000,gid=1000
else
        sudo umount /mnt/some-mount
        sudo rm -rf /mnt/some-mount
fi
echo "Done"
```

I've tried and tinkered around with the options of `davfs`. I was unable to get it to automate correctly. Adding the WebDAV share to the `/etc/fstab` works and adding the login to the `/etc/davfs/secrets`.

I read in the docs of `davfs2` that you can have a config in `~/.davfs2` but `sudo mount /mnt/webdav-share` with `/mnt/webdav-share` in the personal config doesn't work and mount complains that there's no entry in `/etc/fstab` for that mount point.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so there was a multitude of issues and starting from a known good config and working my way to my issues once again did the trick.

Here are the steps I need to take to fix the issues:

1. Create an entry in the `/etc/fstab`
   That entry now looks like this; take note of the `noauto` which circumvents the mounting issues at boot. I think I might add `noexec` and `uid` and `gid` to it as well but for the moment that is minimal and it works.

```
https://domain.com/webdav /mnt/olat     davfs   noauto
```

2. I had an issue with my configuration which stupid me only took way to long to realize.
   2.1  The `davfs2.conf` **doesn't** support the line `noexec 1`
   2.2  The `davfs2.conf` **doesn't** support *fstab-like* lines i.e.

```
https://domain.com/webdav /mnt/some-mountpoint
```

which a tutorial suggested it did.

3. The option `conf` works, provided that your config is correctly formatted and doesn't contain the lines I mentioned above.
4. Having the line

```
secrets ~/.davfs2/secrets
```

in the `/etc/davfs2/davfs2.conf` caused an `unknown option` error.

5. Adding the line :

```
secrets /home/user/.davfs2/secrets
```

to the `~/.davfs2/davfs2.conf` works strangely enough.

6. `~/.davfs2/davfs2.conf` and `~/.davfs2/secrets` need to be owned by `root`.

So to recap:

- Add the mount point and mounting options to `/etc/fstab`
- Watch out what you configure in your `~/.davfs2/davfs2.conf`. Don't add *fstab-like* lines for mount point and options to the davfs2.conf and watch out what you do with your `secrets` file line.
- Add your secrets like in the documentation `[/mount/point or https://share.point/webdav] username "password"` to your user secrets. The `/etc/davfs2/secrets` has examples for you in case you need to check if you have special characters in your password.
- Mount with `sudo mount -t davfs2 /mnt/mountpoint -o conf=~/.davfs2/davfs2.conf` and hopefully (!) everything works.

I hope this helps someone who is struggling with the lack of a password option.

AliSot2000